# Integral of square integrable functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $f$ is continuously differentiable in $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=f(1)=0$. If $\int_0^1f^2(x)dx=1$ then calculate $\int_0^1xf(x)f'(x)dx$.

Try:

Using Leibniz rule we differentiate $\int_0^1f^2(x)dx=1$ to get $\int_0^1f(x)f'(x)dx=0$.

$1=\int_0^12xdx$ $\implies $ Taking inner product $ \langle2x,f(x)f'(x) \rangle=\int_0^12xf(x)f'(x)dx=0$

Hence $\int_0^1xf(x)f'(x)dx=0$.

Is this correct??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is wrong. You get nothing by differentiating the equation $\int f^{2}=1$ because there are no functions in this equation. Here is a correc t argument: $\int_0^{1} xf(x)f'(x)\, dx=\frac 1 2 x(f(x)^{2}|_0^{1} -\frac 1 2\int_0 ^{1} f(x)^{2}\, dx=-\frac 1 2$. [I have used integration by parts and the fact that $\frac d {dx} f(x)^{2}=2f(x)f'(x)$].

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy : Thank you Sir. I realised the blunder I made.